# Is it correct to estimate covariance matrix of null distribution of related random variables using independent groups as data points?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, covariance, covariance-matrix, group-differences

I will use an example of an antidepressant drug trial as an example to illustrate my question - hope this helps as I, too, am confused.

Suppose a study is testing the effects of some drug on people with depression. The participants are split into independent groups, with each group being given a different dose of the drug, including a control group. The authors measure two different related random variables, for example serotonin and dopamine levels in the brain of the participants. Then they write a report and only give the values of the mean levels for each group. Now I want to estimate the covariance between serotonin and dopamine levels for the null distribution of this study.

I understand that if the Null Hypothesis was false, it would be incorrect to simply treat each group as a single sample point and calculate the covariance from there. As fundementally, each group would be sampling from a different distribution due to the unpredictable effects of the drug.

However, if I simply wanted to estimate the covariance of the null distribution, could I then assume that the indepedent groups are all sampling from the same distribution and treat them like individual data points? My reasoning is that if the Null Hypothesis were true, the drug would have no effect and; hence, the distributions for each independent group would be identical.

P.S. Apologies if the answer to this question may appear obvious or if the question was otherwise ill-posed, I am new to statistics and still learning, edits are appreciated!